# Twitter Fabric integration plugin on android studio gradle (build failure)

Tags: android, twitter, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to implement twitter login on my app and followed the fabric tips but i get an error while building the app:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
>   Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

here is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ntg.hatmaak"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
} 

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.marcohc:robotocalendarview:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:0.8.1'
    //compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the full error log.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a "fabric.properties" file which is required to contain API Key and Build Secret, in your app directory ?

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest must contain an `io.fabric.ApiKey`

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="--------------" />
```

Comment: where can get this key ??

Comment: Probably you will get when adding fabric kit into studio.internet connection is required as well in both the device and s/m.